# To remove the mediaLibrary Tab from wp.media

Tags: wordpress, media

I have use a custom button for uploading images to wordpress media. But I dont want the "mediaLibraryTitle" in the popup. I have done this by using this code snippet.

```
function remove_medialibrary_tab($tabs) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        unset($tabs["mediaLibraryTitle"]);
    }
    return $tabs;
}
add_filter('media_view_strings', 'remove_medialibrary_tab');
```

But when i test it is only removing the tab title, But i want remove the tab completely. Also i want to select the "Upload Files" tab by default. Is there any custom function to remove the tab or it can be possible by wp.media function in JS. If yes can you give any idea.

Thank you.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125669/disable-media-library-tab-for-non-admins-in-uploader-screen/125696#125696

Comment: I think you did not test the code, I have mentioned that i want remove the tab, not only the tab text, By "media_view_strings", you can only remove the title.

Comment: did you test ? . did you try the whole code in answer ?

Comment: Yes i have tested the code many times, but i got the tab text remove, not the tab, and i think you forgot i want to select the another tab by default.